# isSelected() method for checkbox always returns true

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to turn on the toggle button if any toggle button is in disabled state , I wanted to let it be if the toggle button is already in enabled state.

```
List<WebElement> allToggle = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body//******-******-****authoring//div//table//td//label"));

for (WebElement Toggle : allToggle) 
{
    if (!Toggle.isSelected()) 
    {
        Toggle.click();
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am being wrong.

Note:- Type of the button is Checkbox

Comment: Check if xpath/css/any element locators  differs for toggle on and off. If so, use it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You trying to invoke `isSelected()` for [label](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) element (based on xpath you've provided).

Based on official Selenium javadoc
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected()

> This operation only applies to input elements such as checkboxes, options in a select and radio buttons.

So `isSelected()` always returns true for non-input elements.

**Solution proposed**

Correct your xpath to refer corresponding **input** element, not **label**.

It can be some `<input type="checkbox">` element in page source.

Also note that for some modern checkbox implementation those ***input*** elements can be hidden and even not directly clickable, anyway, highly likely you'll have to invoke `isSelected()` against those elements, but still need to click on ***label*** to toggle.

So you'll need to iterate by element index and get checkbox input and toggle label both.

```
List<WebElement> checkboxInputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("some-xpath-part-you-need-to-determine/input"));

List<WebElement> allToggle = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body//******-******-****authoring//div//table//td//label"));

int checkboxesCount = allToggle.size();

for (int i = 0; i < checkboxesCount; i++;) {
    if (!checkboxInputs.get(i).isSelected()) {
        allToggle.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @max , i tried multiple way , nothing worked check the below structure


 <label _ngcontent-bpb-c424="" class="switch mr-3">
                <input _ngcontent-bpb-c424="" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" maxlength="500" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><span _ngcontent-bpb-c424="" aria-label="toggle" class="slider round"></span>
            </label>

Comment: Hi @AppasAzlan, from the structure you provided I cannot confirm that checkbox input is hidden, it still can be hidden and unclickable but it's not clear yet. But I see checkbox contains class `ng-untouched`, I guess it means checkbox is not checked, and when you'll toggle it, this class will be removed from element. So you can somehow utilize that fact to determine is checkbox checked or not. You might find input element, and invoke `boolean isSelected = !inputElement.getAttribute("class").contains("untouched");`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did create a solution that worked also.

The problem is there are two sections for every checkbox, one is the `<Input>` tag and the another one is the `<Span>`tag. The input tag has the status about that checkbox is checked or not,  `& but click action` will not work with input, it only works with Span, so I handled it this way:

```java
protected void disableToggle(By Span_Path, By InputPath) {
  if (!driver.findElement(InputPath).isSelected()) {
    System.out.println(" Toggle is Already Disabled ");

  } else if (driver.findElement(InputPath).isSelected()) {
     click(Span_Path, WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE, "Toggle Button Disabled");

  }
}
```